# jdbc connection, login failed for user in war file

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, tomcat, jdbc

I use the following code:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

// Make connection
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://sqltest.ABC.com:1433;databaseName=test5;integratedSecurity=true");
```

If I run my project in Eclipse under Tomcat server goes well. But if I export my project as a WAR file en start the tomcat appache I get the error message " Login failed for user 'DomainName / ServerName'.

I do not know how he got these login data!

Answer (score 0):

You use **integrated authentication** with your database. So you'll need the authentication dll provided by microsoft in your `java.library.path`. If you run tomcat as a service, your service has to run as a user with access privileges on your db as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jan. It works. 

I had already copied the dll file in java path . I must only to change the Log On As of tomcat service user who had access to sql server .